# How to ask a neighbor to support my job application with their organisation?

Tags: applications

My neighbor is a VIP at an organisation that I would like to work for, we currently have a light level of interaction where we greet each other in a friendly way. I have applied for a job opening there but I would like to ask him if he could help with my application. But I don't know how to do that? I am afraid of not finding the right words and losing this unique opportunity.

How can I best approach him for help?

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't know how to do that? I am afraid of not finding the right
>   words and loosing this unique opportunity.

Just ask.

Something like this might work.

"Hey, neighbor. I saw that your company has an opening for a Junior Framis Engineer and I applied for it. Can I use you as a reference? Can you give me any tips about that job or the company?"

Comment: Perhaps not ask for a reference? Seems like OP and the neighbor do not know each other in a capacity where the neighbor should give a reference.